# SQL Oracle - How to exclude multiple rows based of shared criteria between them

Tags: sql

I am looking for correct sql-oracle code to remove multiple lines from a table query where two criteria is the same between the two lines.

Please find example code below and table results (actual and desired)

```
SELECT *
FROM datatable
ORDER BY sequence

SEQUENCE   INSTANCE   NAME     LOGNUMBER   DATAFLAG
100        200        APPLE    20
101        201        ORANGE   30
102        202        GRAPE    40
103        203        BANANA   50
104        201        ORANGE   30           Y
105        205        CHERRY   60
106        202        GRAPE    40           Y
```

In the above data result, I would like lines that have the same "instance" and "lognumber" excluded.

Every data line with a "dataflag" of Y has a corresponding line that needs to be removed with it, so I can't simply use WHERE dataflag <> "Y"

In actual database table, the "instance" and "lognumber" are values that would always be numeric and always different (from each other). For example, Instance value could be 56983145 and LogNumber value could be 54

```
SEQUENCE   INSTANCE   NAME     LOGNUMBER   DATAFLAG
100        200        APPLE    20
103        203        BANANA   50
105        205        CHERRY   60
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Comment: had to edit post to show sample data and desired output.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from datatable t1
where not exists (
                 select 1 from datatable t2 
                  where t1.INSTANCE = t2.INSTANCE 
                  and t1.LOGNUMBER = t2.LOGNUMBER
                  and t2.DATAFLAG = 'Y'
                  )
```

and you can use the same query to delete them

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wrote code as below and it resulted in no values. 
`SELECT *
FROM table t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t1.INSTANCE = t2.INSTANCE AND t2.DATAFLAG = 'Y'
ORDER BY instance`

Comment: @Kowl , did you replace 'table' with your tablename? based on your sample data that is what you want.

Comment: Yes, the table (or datatable) for both t1 and t2 is replaced by the actual database table name.

Comment: @Kowl then you have provided wrong sample data

Comment: I appreciate you looking.  I have reviewed the sample data and it is accurate.  I need to exclude the lines where INSTANCE and LOGNUMBER are the same.  In the sample data, that would be SEQUENCE lines 101, 102, 104, 106 since the lines 101 and 104 both have an INSTANCE of 201 and a LOGNUMBER of 30... and lines 102 and 106 both have an INSTANCE of 202 and a LOGNUMBER of 40.

Comment: I was able to verify your above based on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fea0b/3/0

Comment: @Kowl then issue is something else not the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from datatable a
where (select count(1) from datatable b where a.instance = b.instance and a.lognumber = b.lognumber) = 1
```

By the way, answer from @eshirvana is also giving the same results as the above query with sample data provided in the question. Difference is the approach, I am comparing LOGNUMBER and INSTANCE column while @eshirvana used DATAFLAG column.

Updated Query for performance:

```
with CTE_Exclude1 as(
select Instance, Lognumber
from DataTable
group by Instance, Lognumber
having count(1) = 2
)
Select a.*
from DataTable a Left join CTE_Exclude1 b on a.instance = b.instance 
and a.lognumber = b.lognumber
where b.instance is NULL
```

Comment: This works as well in SQLfiddle.  Both of your answers appear to be correct.  I just need to figure out how to make it work in the real code.

Comment: I was able to get this function to work in my code, but when the dataset has almost 10,000 lines of data to compare, it is running an awfully long time.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Kowl, please check the updated query in my answer.